# Visual Basic (for Applications) Learning Resources

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

As resident techie I have been charged with teaching some colleagues VB specifically for use with Excel.

My main duties involve MySQL and Objective-C and haven't touched VB since University. While I'm not worried about the prospect of learning VB (how hard can it be, right?). I have no clue on where to point my "students" to start.

Any good books? Online tutorials? I will of-course be sending them to SO.

Comment: See this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543424/documentation-resource-for-office-vba-developers/1545024#1545024

Comment: for a basic start:http://multiskillz.tekcities.com/io20_IT_ENG_0080_Vba_MENU_0_table1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like [VBA Developer's Handbook](http://books.google.com/books?id=46toCUvklIQC&dq=vba+developer's+handbook/) by Getz and Gilbert for a book. On the internets, I always wind up at [ozgrid.com](http://www.ozgrid.com/) and [cpearson.com](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/MainPage.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

[About.com](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/learnvba/Learn_to_program_using_Visual_Basic_for_Applications_VBA.htm) often has good stuff.

After that maybe some [Free VBA Tutorials](http://www.your-save-time-and-improve-quality-technologies-online-resource.com/free-vba-tutorials.html)

Answer (score 2):

Google search came up with - http://www.vbtutor.net/VBA/vba_tutorial.html this one is very basic and probably you will just have to breeze thru it and then probably move on to my personal favorite www.ozgrid.com